# Java jsoup connection issue

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to get information on a stock but it is not working (i will eventually put the ticker as a input for a function) I am trying to get the earnings per share and the price to earnings ratio but i keep getting this error. How would i fix this? At the very least i just need jsoup to be able to access the html code. Essentially I want the code to output 15.62 from the P/E ratio.

This my code:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

class Main {
    static Document document;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException{

   Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl").get();
   Elements elements = doc.select("div#table-table fontS14px");
        System.out.println(elements.get(1).getAllElements().get(0).toString());
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:746)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:689)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1604)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:527)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:750)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
```

this is the html that i am trying to read:

```
<div class="table-table fontS14px">

                <div class="table-row" style="">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>P/E Ratio</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        17.23
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="table-row" style="">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Forward P/E (1y)</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        15.62
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="table-row" style="">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Earnings Per Share (EPS)</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        $&nbsp;11.87
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Annualized Dividend</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        $ 2.92
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Ex Dividend Date</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        11/8/2018
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Dividend Payment Date</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        11/15/2018
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Current Yield</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        1.39 %
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-row" style="">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <b>Beta</b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        1.02
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I changed that already and it had the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link does not work because before accessing it redirects you a lot of times, and JSOUP just takes the static context, that's why you are getting that error code every time.

The problem is with Nasqad in particular, so if you want to retrieve stock information for any ticker I'll highly recommend you to crawl [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com), because it works better, and if you just want the info, there's a lot of wrappers like [yahoo-finance-fix](https://pypi.org/project/fix-yahoo-finance/) for Python or [Java Finance Quotes](https://financequotes-api.com) for Java.

I have a Nasqad ETF crawler made using Java but on a private repository on GitHub, if you need it ask me for it and I'll invite you to the repo or something!

Hope it helped you! Feel free to ask for anything else!

Comment: Thanks, I tried the Yahoo Finance library and it works very well but I am interested in your etf crawler, if you are able, i would like an invite

Answer (score 0):

Seems the URL trying seems it self not reachable, you just try that in your browser first,  is it accessible?  If yes then try to set the timeout explicitly for example Jsoup.connect("...").timeout(10*1000).get()

Comment: The link is accessible

Comment: I tried it with (10*1000) and (10*10000) timeout seperately and it didnt work either time

Answer (score 0):

Use the free financial data API

- https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/#stocks

I developed a similar scraper using the NASDAQ website in the past. The NASDAQ website (similar to other websites) is DDoS protected, and uses throttling. Hence, crawling the NASDAQ website either requires you to set HTTP headers to the extend of simulating a browser-based HTTP request. For example, if the `User-Agent` header is empty, or the session isn't attached to your request, NASDAQ will block your request. Also, setting the correct `Referrer` and `X-Requested-With` headers will be required.

You can determine the required headers and cookies by

1. opening the Dev Tools in Chrome,
2. switch to the Network tab,
3. load the page you try to scrape,
4. click on each row (representing a single request/response),
5. find the row that contains the response you are looking for (eg. GET /symbol/aapl)
6. find the `Request Headers` section in the details
7. use those headers in your **scraper** (cookies and realms may expire, ie requiring you to run through steps 1. to 7. again)

If you need API access to ETF data, you can use the `etfdb-api` Node.js package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/etfdb-api

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package :)